# What is the Map Collection type in salesforce

Tags: apex, map

I have been studying type of collection in salesforce. Can you explain what exactly is Map in the types of Collections in the best possible way? I have some articles but I still cant understand it clearly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you find my answer useful then please appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

A map is a collection of key-value pairs where each unique key maps to a single value. Keys and values can be any data type—primitive types, collections, sObjects, user-defined types, and built-in Apex types. For example if you have some country data as follow

```
Key        value

IND        India

US         USA

AUS        Australia

CHI        CHINA
```

it can be added to a map in following way

```
Map<String,String> countryMap = new Map<String,String>();
countryMap('IND','India');
countryMap('US','Usa');
countryMap('AUS','Australia');
countryMap('CHI','China');
```

once it is defined in way you can get value of any country code with out looping through whole collection of items as we generally do with List type collection.

```
countryMap.get('CHI');
```

above code will return China as result.

Map collection is quite useful while working in trigger to store sObject data.

Answer (score 2):

Map is Collection which contains Key-Value pair. Each element has a key and corresponding value.

Syntax:

```
Map <<"datatypeofkey, datatypeofvalue">> var=new Map <<"datatypeofkey, datatypeofvalue">>();
```

Key and value support almost all data type.
below are some interesting methods available to play on map and will tell why using map is beneficial:

```
Map m = new Map{5 => 'Jon', 6 => 'Quinton', 1 => 'Reid'};  
// displays all keys
System.debug('=== all keys in the map: ' + m.keySet());  
// displays all values
System.debug('=== all values in the map (as a List): ' + m.values());  
// does the key exist?
System.debug('=== does key 6 exist?: ' + m.containsKey(6));  
// fetches the value for the key
System.debug('=== value for key 6: ' + m.get(6));  
// adds a new key/value pair
m.put(3,'Dave');  
// returns the number of elements
System.debug('=== size after adding Dave: ' + m.size());  
// removes an element
m.remove(5);  
System.debug('=== size after removing Jon: ' + m.size());  
// clones the map
Map m1 = m.clone();  
System.debug('=== cloned m1: ' + m1);  
// removes all elements
m.clear();  
// returns true if zero elements
System.debug('=== is m empty? ' + m.isEmpty());
```

One more important use of map is you can create map directly from query:

```
Map<Id, Account> m = new Map<Id, Account>([Select name from Account]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**What is MAP?**

A Map is a collection of key-value pairs. Keys can be any `primitive data type` while values can include `primitives, Apex objects, sObjects and other collections`. Use a map when you want to quickly find something by a key. Each key must be unique but you can have duplicate values in your Map.

**Short Description:**

Map holds key and value pair in simple terms.

**Syntax:**

`Map<datatype,datatype> mapName = new Map<datatype,datatype>();`

**Methods Available in MAP:**

```
keyset(): To retrive only keys from the map.
values(): To retrive only values from the map.
containsKey(value): To find a key from the map.
get(key): By passing the key we can retrive the value.
put(key,value): To add new key and value in a map.
```

**Maximum Size:**

No limit for the size of a MAP. It only depends on the heap size which is 6 MB (Synchronous) and 12 MB (Asynchronous).

**Example:**

```
Map<string,string> countryISTCodeMap = new Map<string,string>();
countryISTCodeMap.put('India','91');
countryISTCodeMap.put('USA','001');
countryISTCodeMap.put('India','911');//replaces old value with new value.

Map<string,string> countryISTCodeMap = new Map<string,string>{'India'=>'91','USA'=>'001', 'India'=>'911'};
```

> Note : Map keys are case-sensitive. Hence key value `India` and
>   `india` are treated as different keys in map.